# Trying to determine if NHibernate or anything else would apply for accessing a web service

Tags: .net, architecture, service, data-access-layer

Here's the situation.

We have a 3rd party middleware (using SQLServer as a back-end) which we communicate with using an HTTP service link and XMLRPC-like messaging.

The service always returns a dataset as results of any commands that returns something. There is a way to pass an embedded SQL statement to the service.

So, we do not have a direct access to the database.

I'm trying to isolate this service with a layer that would simplify access. I was thinking of using an ORM like NHibernate.

Is this scenario supported by NHibernate or does NH always needs a direct access to the database?

If you have any other suggestions I'm all ears open...

Comment: Can you add a new middleware layer - say a WCF service(s)? or must you use the 3rd party middleware?

Comment: That is one idea I'm tinkering with. I would add another layer using WCF and perhaps Agatha and that would talk to the other middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're forced to use the 3rd party middle-ware - but it's not easy to deal with?

I've never used NHibernate so I can't speak for that.

Sounds like you want to add a new "service layer" (for want of a better term) on the top that's easier to deal with; the [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) leaps to mind (although that's often used to bundle up a variety of different and disparate interfaces underneath a single cohesive integration point).

Basically you want to define a nice clean set of interfaces / services (in the new service layer); this new layer will then do all the hard work of interacting with the middle-ware - or with the database directly if you get the chance.

I would also suggest making this new layer into a couple of sub-parts: you don't want to go and build a new layer that's tightly coupled to the middle-ware (or database) - use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) to isolate the outer facade from the concrete implementation, and maintain [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling).  That way if the middle-ware disappears you won't directly impact consumers of the new service layer you've built.

Lastly, keep the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (ISP) in mind when designing the new externally facing services.

[Free Image Hosting http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/89e5a8a47a.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/89e5a8a47a.jpg)
([Full size image here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?89e5a8a47a.jpg))

Comment: That's what I had in mind but still I want to have some way of handling transactions (they are supported by the 3rd party middleware). I was thinking of using the repository and unit of work patterns but somehow I can't seem to wrap my mind around them even after countless days of reading about them. I haven't found yet a good example in source code.

Answer (score 0):

We use NHibernate and it sucks.  I would not recommend it for anything.  As for as I know, NHibernate does require direct access to the database (or at least you just give NHibernate a connection string like you would any other data access provider).  Also, because of that, I'm pretty sure it won't know how to handle Xml datasets.

Comment: Interesting - I've never used NHibernate, and of the few people I know who have used it not many swear by it - yet it seems to have a large-ish (?) community.